# how to find out if running from terminal or GUI

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to build a class that would behave is a different way if run using a shell or from a GUI.

It could be included in both forms using #include "myclass.h"...

However, in the constructor I would like to differentiate between Shell runs and GUI runs.

I can easily achieve it using a parameter that would be passed to the constructor when declaring it but I want to explore my options.

I am using C++ on ubuntu and my GUI is using Qt.

Comment: hmm that's twisted ... can I ask you why ? It is generally considered good practice for the "core" modules to be blind about the view using them.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but you could try dynamic casting the [qApp macro](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qapplication.html#qApp) to QApplication. If it's a GUI program, you should get a successful cast. Otherwise it's a QCoreApplication pointer.

Comment: Is `xterm` a terminal or a GUI?

Comment: Vlad: I want automatic detection. I specified that I can do it manual if I don't find any automatic way.
@georgesl: You have more options in a GUI, e.g. colors that you like in a shell. It would be nice to take advantage of these features

Comment: This sounds like a code smell to me. Aside from the front end of your application, your core classes should not need to know what front end (if any!) is being used.

Comment: What do you mean by "running in a shell"? Does terminal emulators with GUI count here? Or you want to distinguish pure tty from pseudo-terminal in X Window?

Comment: nop terminal emulators with GUI's don't count as GUIs.

Comment: So how do you start your program in the GUI form?

Comment: @n.m. Double-clicking, Alt-F2, gnome-menu, ... Everything where no "tty" is present.

Comment: The only difference between running a program with a click and running if from `xterm` is that in the former case the standard input/output/error are not connected to a terminal. So what you are trying to achieve is detecting a terminal, not detecting GUI. If a terminal is present, GUI is ignored and the program runs in terminal mode, which is apparently the primary mode. Is that correct?

Answer (score 9):

The standard C way of determining whether X Window is present:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

if (NULL == getenv("DISPLAY")) is_gui_present = false;
else is_gui_present = true;
```

- this allows to distinguish pseudo-terminals in terminal emulator and pure tty launch.

If you want to determine if there is a shell at all, or the application was run from, say, a file manager, then it's not easy: both cases are just call of `exec` system call from a shell or a file manager/GUI program runner (often with the same parameters), you need to pass a flag explicitly to see that.

P.S. I've just found a way to do that: check the environment for variable "TERM" - it is set for a shell and is inherited to Qt program, it is often not set in a GUI program. But don't take this as an accurate solution!

Comment: I don't think that's what the OPS asks. As I understand it, he wants to know whether the program was launched through the GUI (like double clicking on it), rather than from the CLI.

Comment: @NikosC. some people will get here while looking for this solution as well +1 from me

Answer (score 6):

Launching programs from the desktop (double click or from a desktop file/start menu) will usually redirect their stdin file descriptor to a pipe. You can detect this:

```
#include <cstdio>    // fileno()
#include <unistd.h>  // isatty()

if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
    // We were launched from the command line.
else
    // We were launched from inside the desktop
```