# Check if running in X Window

Tags: c, x11

Linux C program:

What function call can check if running in X Window?

If not in X Window, then printf.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, but maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13204177/856199

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

  // ...

  char *display_name = NULL;

  /* connect to X server */
  if ( (display=XOpenDisplay(display_name)) == NULL )
  {
    //printf or whatever
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "running in X Window"? Do you mean whether your app is running inside a terminal emulator, like `rxvt` or `xterm` instead of a physical console? If so you could use the `TERM` variable I guess, but it's not reliable (since the user can change it to whatever).

The more important quesion is why is this information important to your application?